# how to bypass video conversion for mp4 files?

Tags: 7, files

I am using the [Video](https://drupal.org/project/video) module on my site, and would like a would like to bypass video conversion and a user uploads a file in MP4 format.

Is there any way that the bypass video conversion?

The reason for this is that due to the high volume of video submissions, and the fact that most often the video is already mp4.  The conversion takes a lot of hard drive space, and also required a lot of RAM and CPU resources.  I am hoping that bypassing some of the unnecessary conversions will help alleviate this problem.

Comment: Are you using a module? a regular file field shouldn't be converting anything.

Comment: @Geoff yes I'm using video module

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, look at these options under admin/config/media/video

- Bypass video conversion

  (Bypass video conversion when creating videos.)
- Video convert on node submit

  (Convert videos on node submit will enable by default for all users.)

Comment: i know. this option bypass all video conversion. i want when user upload mp4 file bypass conversion i do not want conversion mp4 to mp4

Comment: So it converts anyways?, even to the same format? does it do this imediately upon submitting the node or as part of a schedule some time later?

Comment: My problem is that due to the high volume of video submissions And how often the video is mp4.
It takes a lot of hard drive space .
The problem of conversion video RAM and CPU consumption is too high 
I consider that the solution to my problem 
i think bypass converting mp4 videos and most videos that users upload to mp4.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Video looks like it has Rules integration - you could try doing it that way - upon node publish, if the field contains .mp4 do nothing, and if not, force it to transcode.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: You can find Rules here (https://drupal.org/project/rules). Read the documentation and do a search, there are lots of tutorials out there. I don't know Video well, so I can't speak to how well it is integrated into Rules and if this will even work, but I would 1) disable all video conversion within Video 2) enable rules triiger on publish of that content-type 3) set Rules condition on whether that field contains "mp4" 4) and if it does not contain mp4, run the video conversion.  You will have to do some research to find out if Rules can run the conversion though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I know the workings of the rules and worked well with. 
there are no action for my problem. I'm looking for a way to solve the problem by coding

Comment: I don't know anything about the code in that module, so I can't help you much, sorry. You should be able to put in a condition within the module though at the beginning of the conversion process